# Upload XLSX to XDocument changes the number format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-xml, xlsx

I have the following method to take an XLSX file and convert it to an XDocument:

```
 public static XDocument ConvertXlsx2Xml(string fileName, string sheetName)
 {
        //  Return the value of the specified cell.
        const string documentRelationshipType = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument";
        const string worksheetSchema = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";
        const string sharedStringsRelationshipType = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/sharedStrings";
        const string sharedStringSchema = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";

        string cellValue = null;

        var xsurvey = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"));
        var xroot = new XElement("Root"); //Create the root


        using (Package xlPackage = Package.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            PackagePart documentPart = null;
            Uri documentUri = null;

            //  Get the main document part (workbook.xml).
            foreach (System.IO.Packaging.PackageRelationship relationship in xlPackage.GetRelationshipsByType(documentRelationshipType))
            {
                //  There should only be one document part in the package. 
                documentUri = PackUriHelper.ResolvePartUri(new Uri("/", UriKind.Relative), relationship.TargetUri);
                documentPart = xlPackage.GetPart(documentUri);
                //  There should only be one instance, but get out no matter what.
                break;
            }

            if (documentPart != null)
            {
                // Load the contents of the workbook.
                var doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(documentPart.GetStream());
                /*
                    doc now contains the following important nodes:
                    <bookViews>
                        <workbookView xWindow="-15615" yWindow="2535" windowWidth="26835" windowHeight="13095" activeTab="2" />
                    <sheets>
                        <sheet name="Sheet1" sheetId="2" r:id="rId1" />
                 */

                //  Create a namespace manager, so you can search.
                //  Add a prefix (d) for the default namespace.
                var nt = new NameTable();
                var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
                nsManager.AddNamespace("d", worksheetSchema);
                nsManager.AddNamespace("s", sharedStringSchema);

                //If value for sheetName isn't found, take the first sheet
                string searchString = string.Format("//d:sheet[@name='{0}']", sheetName);
                XmlNode sheetNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(searchString, nsManager) ??
                                    doc.SelectSingleNode("//d:sheet", nsManager);

                /*  
                 * 11/15/12 DS Added to avoid pulling the data each time
                 * Create a dictionary of the shared strings from the associated string file
                 */
                #region Shared String Dictionary
                var sharedStrings = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                foreach (System.IO.Packaging.PackageRelationship stringRelationship in documentPart.GetRelationshipsByType(sharedStringsRelationshipType))
                {
                    //  There should only be one shared string reference, so you exit this loop immediately.
                    Uri sharedStringsUri = PackUriHelper.ResolvePartUri(documentUri, stringRelationship.TargetUri);
                    PackagePart stringPart = xlPackage.GetPart(sharedStringsUri);
                    {
                        //  Load the contents of the shared strings.
                        var stringDoc = new XmlDocument(nt);
                        stringDoc.Load(stringPart.GetStream());
                        nsManager.AddNamespace("s", sharedStringSchema);

                        const string strSearch = "//s:sst";
                        XmlNode stringNode = stringDoc.SelectSingleNode(strSearch, nsManager);
                        int keyInt = 0;
                        if (stringNode != null)
                            foreach (XmlElement nd in stringNode)
                            {
                                //string test = nd.InnerText;
                                sharedStrings.Add(keyInt, nd.InnerText);
                                keyInt = keyInt + 1;
                            }
                    }
                }
                #endregion

                var hrowList = new List<string>();
                var hrowArray = new string[] {};

                if (sheetNode != null && sheetNode.Attributes != null)
                {
                    //  Get the relId attribute:
                    XmlAttribute relationAttribute = sheetNode.Attributes["r:id"];
                    if (relationAttribute != null)
                    {
                        string relId = relationAttribute.Value;

                        //  First, get the relation between the document and the sheet.
                        PackageRelationship sheetRelation = documentPart.GetRelationship(relId);
                        Uri sheetUri = PackUriHelper.ResolvePartUri(documentUri, sheetRelation.TargetUri);
                        PackagePart sheetPart = xlPackage.GetPart(sheetUri);

                        //  Load the contents of the workbook.
                        var sheetDoc = new XmlDocument(nt);
                        sheetDoc.Load(sheetPart.GetStream());
                        /* 
                         *  sheetDoc now contains the following important nodes:
                         *  <dimension ref="A1:V81" />                  range of sheet data
                         *  <sheetData>
                         *     <row r="1" spans="1:22">                <row> r = row number, spans = columns containing the data
                         *         <c r="A1" t="s"><v>0</v></c>        <c> r = Cell address (A1,B4,etc), t = data type ("s"=string,"b"=bool, null=decimal)  
                         *                                             <v> contents are the index num if t="s", or value of t=null
                         */
                        XmlNode sheetDataNode = sheetDoc.SelectSingleNode("//d:sheetData", nsManager);
                        int roNum = 0;
                        if (sheetDataNode != null)
                        {
                            var isSkip = false;
                            foreach (XmlElement row in sheetDataNode)
                            {
                                var xrow = new XElement("Row");
                                foreach (XmlElement cell in row)
                                {
                                    XmlAttribute typeAttr = cell.Attributes["t"];
                                    string cellType = typeAttr != null ? typeAttr.Value : string.Empty;

                                    XmlNode valueNode = cell.SelectSingleNode("d:v", nsManager);
                                    cellValue = valueNode != null ? valueNode.InnerText : cellValue;

                                    //  Check the cell type. At this point, this code only checks for booleans and strings individually.
                                    switch (cellType)
                                    {
                                        case "b":
                                            cellValue = cellValue == "1" ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
                                            break;
                                        case "s":
                                            cellValue = sharedStrings[Convert.ToInt32(cellValue)];
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    if (cellValue == null) continue;
                                    cellValue = cellValue.Replace("\r", "");
                                    cellValue = cellValue.Replace("\n", " ");
                                    cellValue = cellValue.Trim();
                                    if (roNum == 0)
                                    {
                                        hrowList.Add(cellValue);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //XmlAttribute rowAttr = cell.Attributes["r"];
                                        //int intStart = rowAttr.Value.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());
                                        //colLet = rowAttr.Value.Substring(0, intStart);
                                        //int colNum = NumberFromExcelColumn(colLet);
                                        int colNum = GetColNum(cell);

                                        /* 05/29/13 DS force column names to UPPER to remove case sensitivity */
                                        var xvar = new XElement(hrowArray[colNum - 1].ToUpper());
                                        xvar.SetValue(cellValue);
                                        xrow.Add(xvar);
                                    }
                                    /* 6/18/2013 DS You must clear the cellValue so it is carried into the next cell value if it is empty. */
                                    cellValue = "";
                                }
                                if (roNum == 0) hrowArray = hrowList.ToArray(); 
                                else  xroot.Add(xrow); 
                                roNum = roNum + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        xsurvey.Add(xroot);
        return xsurvey;
    }
```

For the most part, it works very well.  However, I have just noticed that if one of the cell values contains a number like 0.004 it becomes 4.0000000000000001E-3.

The resulting XML gets imported and that value is loaded as a string, but before the final transfer to the production tables, this particular field is converted to numeric.  That format doesn't work with numeric.

How do I prevent that change on load?  If I can't, is there a better method to prevent a system error, other than specifically scrubbing that field and changing it back as part of the transfer process?

**UPDATE**

It is only numbers less than .01 that have a problem.  1, 1.004, and .04 are fine, but .004 is not.

**UPDATE 2**

If I format the cells as text BEFORE populating the data, I do not have this issue.  There is something about how ManEx stores the data that prevents a clean upload.

Answer (score 0):

Read value as double with invariant culture, and then convert it to decimal

```
var cellValueDouble = Convert.ToDouble(cellValue,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var cellValueDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(cellValueDouble);
```